# JavaFX TableView Editing an empty row

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx `TableView`,

```
public class CellEditingExample extends Application {
        private final TableView table = new TableView();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList( new Person("A"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        TableColumn firstNameCol = createSimpleFirstNameColumn();
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);
        table.setEditable(true);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn createSimpleFirstNameColumn() {
        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                t.getRowValue().setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                                System.out.println("Table Size is : " + table.getItems().size());
            }
        });
        return firstNameCol;
    }
}
```

and the `Person.java` is,

```
public class Person {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;

    public Person(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

If we run the application,
    we get a Table with one row having "A" as value and that row is editable.

I want to edit the next row as well even when there is no value (also without affecting the items size of the table),

i have tried,

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList( new Person("A"),new Person("")); // This increases getItems().Size();
FXCollections.observableArrayList( new Person("A"),null); // NullPointerException is thrown
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What is the desired behavior for this "empty" row?  The item count in the table is simply the number of entries in it's `items` property, but as far as I know you can't ask the `TableView` to edit an empty row. The simplest solution is probably to add a new item to the table and mark it as "temporary" in some way, then delete it if the user doesn't enter any value, or mark it as persistent if they do.

Comment: @sillyfly As of now i have handled by adding a temporary row. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to edit without adding the temporary row.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with `TableView` (maybe possible if you subclass it, but that is probably overkill), but as I'm not sure I'll leave it to the JavaFX experts around here to give a definitive answer.